# Do not Trigger OnFocus when Click is triggered

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I have the following XAML:

```
<Button ToolTip="Save" x:Name="SaveBtn" GotFocus="SaveBtn_GotFocus" Click="SaveBtn_Click">
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ContentSave" IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="50" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
</Button>
```

This Button has two events, onFocus and Click; this is because the button will get focus usually with TAB; but sometimes a manual save (Click) has to occur.

```
private void SaveBtn_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveButton();
}

private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveButton();
}

private void SaveButton ()
{
    ErrorSnackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue($"Het veld Serienummer is verplicht!", neverConsiderToBeDuplicate: true);
}
```

The issue is that both GotFocus and Click are triggered when the button is Clicked, thus saving the record twice.

How do I disable the GotFocus trigger when the button is clicked?

ps, I have to have both Click and OnFocus. The 'ErrorSnackbar' doesn't trigger otherwise

Comment: I don't think you can. How is this a problem? What do you normally do when the button gains focus?

Comment: Why do you need to handle the `Click` event? The `Button` should get focused when it's clicked anyway so handling only `GotFocus` should be enough.

Comment: I Updated the original question; I don't display a messagebox, but a Snackbar (MaterialDesignInXML), which doesn't trigger every time with OnFocus, but does so with the Click Event

Comment: the mouse is barely used when you use a Barcodescanner, and are ~100 meter away from your pc. That's why It should respond on Tab (OnFocus)

Comment: Can you not use a Command instead?

Comment: Hm. That's a good comment.. use a Command with CanExecute instead of checking after the button is pressed, however: I have never used a Command before.. will look into that..

Comment: Doing this completely breaks how keyboard access is supposed to work in Windows.  Tab is used to navigate between controls.  Space activates the currently focused control (check a checkbox, click a button, etc).  Enter activates the default button, escape activates the cancel button.  Don't use Click handlers for this, bind to the Command property of the button instead.

Comment: Could you work with the tab or whatever you get sent to the textbox by the scanner?